# Javascript Regular Expression for removing text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I want to replace a string of characters in an html tag using JavaScript. So in this example I want to remove everything between the `<table` and `<tbody>`. I'm using the replace function and a regular expression. The regular expression construction must be wrong somewhere. Here is what I currently have:

```
str = str.replace(/([<table]\w*\W*[<tbody>])/, "");
```

The regular expression logic as I see it is like this (correct me where I'm wrong):

1. I'm looking for the string match of `<table` so I put that string in the brackets as I want that to match exactly as written.
2. Then I place a \w*\W* because I expect 1 or more of both
   alphanumeric and non alphanumeric characters to follow.
3. Finally I
       place the "< tbody>" in the brackets because I expect that format
       exactly.

So the results are not as I expected. There is no other `<tbody>` or `<table` in my string so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is what the string looks like before I replace the characters with nothing.

```
"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n                                                <div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
<table id=\"gvStation_ctl19_gvExtRows\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\" border=\"1\" rules=\"all\" cellspacing=\"0\">
\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tbody>
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: What reference material are you using to learn/understand regular expression? (You have the wrong information)

Comment: Characteres inside [] doesn't represent a word, it will match one of any characters inside it ex: `[<table]` can match letters `t` or `a`, but will not match `ta` or `tt` for example without + or * modifier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The brackets find any character between in any order so you don't need it in this case. See [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).
2. `\w*` and `\W*` don't match the whitespaces.

Here is the solution : `/<\s*table(?:.|\s)*<\s*tbody\s*>/i`

```js
var str = '"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n < div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t < table id=\"gvStation_ctl19_gvExtRows\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\" border=\"1\" rules=\"all\" cellspacing=\"0\"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t< tbody>';

str = str.replace(/<\s*table(?:.|\s)*<\s*tbody\s*>/i, "");

alert(str);
```